# replication between mysql 5.5 and mariaDB 10.2

Tags: mysql, replication

i'm implementing master-slave replication between mysql 5.5(master) and mariaDB 10.2 (slave) and i'm getting error such as in slave

```
Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master
```

here is my configurations

i'm running mysql 5.5 (master) as standalone server and mariadb (slave) 10.2 as docker.

in master server -

```
in my.cnf 
    [mysqld]
    log-bin=mysql-bin
    server-id=1
```

create replication user

```
CREATE USER 'repl'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'DuoS123';
 GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'%';
```

getting master binary position

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;

SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

output:-

```
filename : mysql-bin.000004 pos: 904
```

SLAVE SERVER:

```
in my.cnf

[mysqld]
server-id=2

CHANGE MASTER TO   MASTER_HOST='172.31.85.75',  MASTER_USER='repl',   MASTER_PASSWORD='DuoS123',   MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000004',MASTER_LOG_POS=904 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

after some digging i found the solution, i added this line to my mariadb 10.2 my.cnf now works like a charm

```
slave_sql_verify_checksum=0
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue in replication of mysql to mariadb 10.4.18 with the error "Last_IO_Errno: 1595" and "Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master"